# VB.NET: Use property as delegate function

Tags: properties, delegates, c#-to-vb.net

I have got a problem with converting an example from C# to VB.NET.

The C# example has the following structure.
First there is a public delegate.

```
public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender , EventArgs e);
```

This delegate is connected to an property of an interface.

```
public interface ICustom {
    CustomEventHandler MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I have got a class with a function containing the interface as parameter. This property is called with the parameters like a function.

```
public class Test {

    public void MySub(ICustom custom) {
        custom.MyProperty(this, new EventArgs());        }
}
```

I can convert this code except for the use of the property. My VB.NET code looks like the following:

```
Public Delegate Sub CustomEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Public Interface ICustom

    Property MyProperty As CustomEventHandler
End Interface

Public Class Test

    Public Sub MySub(ByVal custom As ICustom)
        ... How can I add here the event OnEvent to the event custom.MyEvent? ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is it possible to convert this or is there another way necessary.
Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

For firing events in VB.NET you have to use `RaiseEvent`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1